# python 3.x what is -> annotation

Tags: python

In the following snippet what is `->` operator ,does it indicate the return type of the function also is it mandatory to use it in python 3.x ? Please point me to few docs for the same

```
 def g() -> str :
    ...
    return 'hello world'
```

Comment: Annotation hinting the return type of the function. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` is an [*annotation*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), attached to the function *return value*. Annotations are optional, but you can use the syntax to attach arbitrary objects to a function. You can attach more annotations by using `name : annotation` on the parameters too.

In the sample you gave, it is being used to create a *type hint*. Type hinting is a new Python 3 extension. It is *not* mandatory, but using type hints can make development in an IDE like PyCharm easier, as well as enable static typechecking by tools like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).

See the [`typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for a set of objects to help create type hints, and the [PEP 484 *Type Hints*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) proposal.

Comment: will the`name: annotation`syntax help increase speed or will they help protect the type of the argument given;does `def func(arg: int):`make it so the interpreter ensures the argument arg gets the input type `int`?Or are they for decoration

Comment: @theX: no, annotations have no influence on the runtime.

Comment: Ah, ok: decoration purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

This is type of return value: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html :) It's not mandatory, but might be usefull.